# Git and DB state

Tags: git

Git is excellent tool: you could switch to the one of previous versions and bisect the history to locate the bug.

But actually you could not, because when you're switching to the old release, your DB remains in its most recent state, so your **Web app** won't work at all.

Is there any common solution on how to work around that?

Some thoughts:

- I can't add the entire DB into every commit
- I can't use migration back and forward, because I'm losing data in back migrations. The data is not a part of the structure, but it is handy for debug.
- And of course, I need something to be in sync with Git (a hook?), otherwise I'm getting extra time expenses which are not well.

Comment: Use backups for your recent data and store the schema of your database  in your git repository as it evolves. Probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be having a script that creates a database with dummy/testing data. Since this script and your database structure would be versioned, it would always create the correct one.

However, you cannot automatically perform a *back-migration* since the information about structure changes happening after the current commit are not available.

Comment: Over the years I ended up with the same solution. If you have a good seed that covers all your important test cases, you could simply recreate the whole database on any checkout.

Answer (score 1):

try this tool

https://hub.docker.com/r/arelis/gitdb

its a version control to mysql and use git for control version

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.